# Web scraping "itemprop" output

Tags: python, web-scraping, output

Hi I wrote the following code to get the location of the city.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Loads the webpage
r = requests.get("https://www.century21.com/for-sale-homes/Westport-CT-20647c", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
#grabs the contect of this page
c=r.content

if "blocked" in r.text:
    print ("we've been blocked")



#makes the content more readable
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

#Prints out the content 
#print(soup.prettify())

#Finds the number of proterty Listed
all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"sr-card js-safe-link"})

#Finds the city of the property of interest
x=all[1].find("div", {"class":"sr-card__city-state"})




for itemprop in x:
        print(x.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality").text)
```

The output of x is as follows

```
<div class="sr-card__city-state">
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Westport</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">CT</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">06880</span>
</div>
```

when my for loop is executed i get the following output

```
Westport
Westport
Westport
Westport
Westport
Westport
Westport
```

While it is printing the correct output I don't understand why its printing it out 7 times. I understand that I am making a mistake but I don't understand where I am making the mistake. I would be really grateful if someone can point in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The length of x is 7 and that is the reason it is showing the output 7 times. you may want to try something like this,

```
#Finds the number of proterty Listed
all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"sr-card js-safe-link"})

#Finds the city of the property of interest
x=all[1].find("div", {"class":"sr-card__city-state"})

print(x)

print(len(x)) # Length of x

for prop in x.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality"):
        print(prop)
```